# How to call removeBody function of physics dynamically on a touch event in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to call removeBody function when i click on an object. As soon as i click
the object the removeBody function must be called on an object and after i release the 
mouse then it must again behave like a physics object. These are the code that i
was trying. please give any suggestion

```
local function removephysics(objId)
   physics.removeBody(objId)
end

local Bodyobject={density=3.0, friction=0.2, bounce=0.3, radius=20}

object1=display.newImage("img1.png")
object1.x=325
object1.y=200
object1.id="obj"
physics.addBody(object1,Bodyobject)
object1.addEventListener("touch",removephysics)
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove an object from physics and add that object again? That doesn't make sense. Are you trying to do drag-drop on physic objects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `event.phase` to get the state of touch listener see this code

```
physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local Bodyobject={density=3.0, friction=0.2, bounce=0.3, radius=20}
function removephysics(event)
   if event.phase == "began" then
      physics.removeBody(object1)
   elseif event.phase == "ended" then
      physics.addBody(object1,Bodyobject)
   end
end


object1=display.newImage("img1.png")
object1.x=325
object1.y=200
object1.id="obj"
physics.addBody(object1,Bodyobject)
object1:addEventListener("touch",removephysics)
```

Comment: In the above code the physics.addBody function is not working properly on objects, I am using your code it calls remove body function properly when i drag mouse over an object and apply force to it, but after dragging and releasing mouse button, the object shifts from its original x y location... is there any other phase where we can call addBody function, i want it to be called after dragging and releasing mouse button... thanks for the above answer

Comment: there are three phases of event touch the "began","moved" and "ended"  you can try it